# CSV file import in .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Any help would be great please! I'm importing Google contacts by CSV. The problem is I can get the value of only specific header of the CSV file as I mentioned in the code. Can anyone get me the source code to get the entire set while importing the Google CSV file?

```
private void GoogleCsv()
{
    StreamReader Sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("CSVLoad//" + FileUpload.FileName));
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    string s;
    Int64 count = 0, flag = 0;
    while (!Sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        s = Sr.ReadLine();

        a = s.Split(',')[0];
        b = s.Split(',')[1];
        c = s.Split(',')[2];
        d = s.Split(',')[3];
        e = s.Split(',')[4];

        if (count == 0)
        {
            if ((a == "Name") && (b == "E-mail 1 - Value") && (c == "Phone 1 - Value") && (d == "Address 1 - Formatted") && (e == "Organization 1 - Name"))
            {
                flag = flag + 1;
                count = count + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (count > 0)
        {
            if (flag == 1)
            {
                Contact contact = new Contact();
                contact.ContactFirstName = a;
                contact.ContactLastName = "";
                contact.ContactEmail = b;
                contact.CompanyName = e;
                contact.ContactPhone = "";
                contact.MobileNo = c;
                contact.Designation = d;
                contact.Streetone = "";
                contact.Streettwo = "";
                contact.Area = "";
                contact.Userid = Convert.ToInt64(Session["UserId"].ToString());
                contact.Organizationid = Convert.ToInt64(Session["OrgId"].ToString());
                contact.Stateid = 19;
                contact.Countryid = 2;
                contact.Createdby = 106;
                contact.Industryid = 287;
                contact.Accgroupid = 627;
                _importController.CsvImportDetails(contact);
            }
        }
    }
    Sr.Close();
    File.Delete(Server.MapPath("CSVLoad//" + FileUpload.FileName));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I use this [CsvReader](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx) class for loading CSV data, it's free, fast and easy to use.

Comment: CsvReader will read the entire CSV file, all columns included.

Answer (score 2):

For anything like that, I always turn to [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/downloads.html). Why reinvent the wheel and struggle around with delimiters and all those gnary details when there's a solution out there that deals with all those low-level aspects already??

Just define the class you want to import (the list of fields, basically), define the delimiters and ignored fields etc., and then just call `FileHelperEngine<T>.ReadFile()` and be done with it.

Highly recommended!

Comment: I've been tempted to use this once or twice, good to here a recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

One interesting and elegant option is the [LINQToCSV](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQtoCSV.aspx) project.

Comment: After testing LINQToCSV and LumenWorks (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx), I decided for the second one. Easy to use and really fast.

Answer (score 0):

```
   class DynamicCSV : DynamicObject
{
private Dictionary<String, int> _fieldIndex;
private string[] _RowValues;
public DynamicCSV(string currentRow, Dictionary<string, int> fieldIndex)
{
    _RowValues = currentRow.Split(',');
    _fieldIndex = fieldIndex;
}


public YOURLINQOBject export() {
  return new YOURLINQOBject() 
}

public DynamicCSV(string[] values, Dictionary<string, int> fieldIndex)
{
    _RowValues = values;
    _fieldIndex = fieldIndex;
    //var that = new DynamicObject();
    //that.TrySetMember(
}



private string TransitionName(string inputFieldName)
{
    return Repo.TransitionThisName(inputFieldName);
}

public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out Object result)
{
    var fieldName = binder.Name.ToUpperInvariant();
    if (_fieldIndex.ContainsKey(fieldName))
    {
        result = _RowValues[_fieldIndex[fieldName]];
        return true;
    }
    result = null;
    return false;
}


public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
{
    var fieldName = binder.Name.ToUpperInvariant();
    if (_fieldIndex.ContainsKey(fieldName))
    {
        _RowValues[_fieldIndex[fieldName]] = value.ToString();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public override string ToString()
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine("*******************************************");
    foreach (var field in _fieldIndex)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(field.Key + " --- " + _RowValues[_fieldIndex[field.Key]]);
    }
    sb.AppendLine("*******************************************");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

}

Then in order to load all the lines together

```
 public class DynamicCSVEnum : IEnumerable
{
    private PeopleEnumerator _peopleEnum;
    public DynamicCSVEnum(string filename)
    {
        _peopleEnum = new PeopleEnumerator(filename);
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator( )
    {
        // return a PeopleEnumerator
        return _peopleEnum;
    }
}


public class PeopleEnumerator : IEnumerator
{
    //private List<MKG> theList;
    //private int _currentIndex;

    private Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser _FileStream;
    private Dictionary<string, int> _FieldNames;
    private DynamicCSV _CurrentRow;
    private string _filename;

    public PeopleEnumerator( string filename)
    {
        _filename = filename;
        //theList = new List<MKG>();
        //theList.Add(new MKG() { Id = 0 });
        //theList.Add(new MKG() { Id = 1 });
        //theList.Add(new MKG() { Id = 2 });
        //_currentIndex = -1;
        GetEnumerator();
    }

    private void GetEnumerator()
    {
        _FileStream = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(_filename);
        _FileStream.Delimiters = new String[] { "," };
        _FileStream.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
        _FileStream.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited;
        var fields = _FileStream.ReadFields();
        _FieldNames = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        for (var i = 0; i <= fields.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            _FieldNames.Add(GetSafeFieldName(fields[i]), i);
        }
        _CurrentRow = new DynamicCSV(_FileStream.ReadFields(), _FieldNames);
    }
    public void Reset()
    {
        //_currentIndex = 0;
        _FileStream.Close();
        GetEnumerator();
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        //_currentIndex++;
        //if (_currentIndex < theList.Count)
        //{

        //    return true;
        //}
        //return false;
        var line = _FileStream.ReadFields();
        if (line != null && line.Length > 0)
        {
            _CurrentRow = new DynamicCSV(line, _FieldNames);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public object Current
    {
        //get
        //{
        //    return theList[_currentIndex];
        //}
        //set
        //{
        //    theList[_currentIndex] = (MKG)value;
        //}
        get { return _CurrentRow; }

    }

    string GetSafeFieldName(string input)
    {
        return input.Replace(" ", "").Replace("_", "").Replace(".","").Replace("#","").Replace("/","").Replace("\\","").ToUpperInvariant();
    }

}
```

Then all it takes is a simple

```
            var foo = new DynamicCSVEnum(savedFileName);

            foreach (DynamicCSV item in foo)
            {
                retVal.Add(item.LinqObjectExport());
            }

            foreach (var item in retVal)
            {
                item.ClientSet = dsid;
            }
            repo.InsertDataSet(retVal);
```